Download media content using powershell
I have a csv file where in path C:\Usman\meetings_export.csv and has a column called media-ID. This column has media ids which are comma separated,
for example: {5625AF3F-F69C-420A-AFE3-B19060F42A43},{8DA1CE9C-D7BD-4093-B0A1-92F6141AEA51},{F32897AD-8EFE-4BE1-AC87-ABA9A96B331F}
My requirements is to have a zip file for each row, and the zip file name should have indication that its associated with what row number.
I am using below script,
 # Read the CSV file" DONT FORGET TO UPDATE"
    $csvData = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Usman\meetings_export.csv"

# Define the function to zip items
function ZipItems($zipArchive, $items) {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("WindowsBase,Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35") > $null

    try {
        $ZipPackage = [System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage]::Open($zipArchive, [System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate, [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite)
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error opening zip archive: $_"
        return
    }

    [byte[]]$buff = new-object byte[] 40960
    $i = 0
    ForEach ($item In $items) {
        $i++
        if([Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager]::HasMediaContent($item)){
            $mediaItem = New-Object "Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem" $item
            $mediaStream = $mediaItem.GetMediaStream()
            $fileName = $item.Name -replace ' ', '_'
            "Added: $fileName"
            Write-Progress -Activity "Zipping Files" -CurrentOperation "Adding $fileName" -Status "$i out of $($items.Length)" -PercentComplete ($i *100 / $items.Length)
            $partUri = New-Object System.Uri($fileName, [System.UriKind]::Relative)
            $partUri = [System.IO.Packaging.PackUriHelper]::CreatePartUri($partUri)
            
            # Check if part exists before creating it
            if (-not $ZipPackage.PartExists($partUri)) {
                $part = $ZipPackage.CreatePart($partUri, "application/zip", [System.IO.Packaging.CompressionOption]::Maximum)
                $stream = $part.GetStream()
                do {
                    $count = $mediaStream.Read($buff, 0, $buff.Length)
                    $stream.Write($buff, 0, $count)
                } while ($count -gt 0)
                $stream.Close()
                $mediaStream.Close()
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        $ZipPackage.Close()
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error closing zip archive: $_"
    }
}

# Counter for tracking row number
$rowNumber = 1

# Loop through each row in the CSV data
foreach ($row in $csvData) {
    
    $mediaIds = $row.'media-ID' -split ',' # Split media IDs by comma
    
    # Initiate the Items Array for the current row
    $items = @()
    
    # Loop through each media ID in the row
    foreach ($mediaId in $mediaIds) {
        $mediaId = $mediaId.Trim() # Remove any leading or trailing whitespace
        
        # Check if Media-ID is not empty
        if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($mediaId)) {
       
            $mediaItemPath = "master:/sitecore/media library"
            
            Write-Host "Media ID: $mediaId"
            Write-Host "Media Item Path: $mediaItemPath"
            
            # Get the media item
            $mediaItem = Get-Item -Path $mediaItemPath -ID $mediaId
            
            # Check if media item exists
            if ($mediaItem -ne $null) {
                # Add media item to the array for this row
                $items += $mediaItem
            } else {
                Write-Host "Media item with ID '$mediaId' not found."
            }
        }
    }
    
    # Define the path for the zip file for this row with row number
    $zipName = "Meetings_Row$rowNumber"
    $time = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-d_hhmmss"
    $zipPath = "C:\Usman\meetings\$zipName-$time.zip"  # Specify the download path directly
    
    # Call the function to zip items for this row
    ZipItems $zipPath $items
    
    # Increment row number
    $rowNumber++
}

# Close the window
Close-Window

This is throwing below error
Exception calling "Write" with "3" argument(s): "There is not enough space on the disk.
"
At line:34 char:21
+                     $stream.Write($buff, 0, $count)
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException


Did you check the space on your disk where the files are being downloaded? If the disk is not an issue please add some more details.

Below are possible reasons for the error:
Insufficient Disk Space: Check the available disk space on the drive where you're attempting to create the zip files (C:\Usman\meetings). If the space is low, you'll need to free up disk space or use a different disk with more available space.
Large Media Files: Media items with large file sizes can consume a significant amount of disk space when zipped. Consider optimizing the media files or using a disk with more available space.
To address the issue, you can:

Free up disk space on the target drive (C:\Usman\meetings) by
deleting unnecessary files or transferring files to a different drive
with more space.
Verify that the media items being zipped are not excessively large.
If they are, it may be helpful to process them in smaller batches or
chunks to reduce the strain on system resources.
Consider using a different drive with more available space for
storing the zip files to ensure sufficient storage capacity.


If there's not enough space on the disk, try designating an alternate destination path ($zipPath) with sufficient free space to store the zip files.o
In case disk space isn't the problem, you can enhance the script for more efficient memory utilization or smaller file sizes. For instance, adjusting the buffer size ($buff) or managing files in smaller groups can help minimize memory usage.
